# SVM-APPLTING SMO algorithm ON A DATASET ( implementation on MATLAB )

Tags: matlab, svm

I want to implement SVM algorithm on a dataset (iris dataset) in MATLAB to know the accuracy and the matric of detailed Accuracy By Class ,

I downloaded the dataset as csv file and import it in MATLAB , MATLAB read the dataset ,
what should I do next so I can find the current accuracy and the detailed Accuracy By Class  that I'm looking for ,
please ! Guide me

Comment: It sounds like you should read the [MATLAB documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/support-vector-machine-classification.html), maybe starting with the Classification Learner app. If you hit a specific problem with your code, ask a question showing the code and explaining the problem.